# How to update the view when cursor gets changes in Android

Tags: android, database, android-listview, android-cursoradapter, android-cursor

Here is how i'm passing cursor to its adapter

```
Cursor c = get_controllerObj().getDBManager().getAllListCursor();



            if(c.moveToFirst())
            {
                mlistsadapter.swapCursor(c);
                mlists.setAdapter(mlistsadapter);
            }
```

If i change content, then i'm doing like this, like update the db with query and then swap cursor.
is this better approach? or anything else apart from this makes much more better?

```
get_controllerObj().getDBManager().updateListNewName(newName, key);
Cursor c = get_controllerObj().getDBManager().getAllListCursor();

                        mTasklistsadapter.swapCursor(c);
```

Comment: call `notifyDatasetChanged`

Comment: simply notify dataset change will work? because my cursor is not refreshed right?

Comment: what do you mean "not refreshed"?

Comment: i mean, my cursor will be pointing to old data items, if i update database with new item, then cursor should also get updated right?

Comment: yes you swapped the new cursor in so you should be good to go